# C using select() to read from two named pipes (FIFO)

Tags: c, select, fifo

I am currently trying to write a program in C which will read from two named pipes and print any data to stdout as it becomes available.

for example:  If I open two terminals and `./execute pipe1 pipe2` in one of the terminals (with pipe1 and pipe2 being valid named pipes) and then type `echo "Data here." > pipe1` then the name of the pipe (here it is `pipe1`), the size, and the data should print to stdout-- Here it would look like `pipe1 [25]: Data here.`

I know I need to open the pipes with the `O_RDONLY` and `O_NONBLOCK` flags. I have looked at many examples (quite a few on this forum) of people using `select()` and I still don't understand what the different parameters being passed to `select()` are doing. If anyone can provide guidance here it would be hugely helpful. Below is the code I have so far.

```
 int pipeRouter(char[] fifo1, char[] fifo2){
    fileDescriptor1 = open(fifo1, O_RDONLY, O_NONBLOCK);
    fileDescriptor2 = open(fifo2, O_RDONLY, O_NONBLOCK);

    if(fileDescriptor1 < 0){
        printf("%s does not exist", fifo1);
    }
    if(fileDescriptor2 < 0){
        printf("%s does not exist", fifo2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the manual page?

Comment: yes, it lists the signature as  int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout); with nfds being the highest number file descriptor plus 1. Not sure how to tell which file descriptor to put here (ive gathered file descriptor is what the low level open() call returns) and readfds will be the independent sets of file descriptors being watched to see if characters become available. So which pipe to put as the nfds arguments and how to include both of my pipes as the readfds argument

Comment: And the page has an example http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Comment: Are you sure that your `open()` calls are correct? As far as I can tell you can't use that 3rd argument like that. I believe it should be `open(fifo1, O_RDONLY | O_NON_BLOCK)`

Comment: Thinking about how `select()` is implemented will help you understand what `nfds` is and how to set it. In the kernel, the select essentially has a `for(fd=0; fd<nfds; fd++)` loop. In the loop it checks the bits set in the `readfds`, `writefds` and `exceptfds` so that it knows which file descriptors to watch. You could actually set `nfds` to `FD_SETSIZE` but it would loop over bits that will never be set, and waste a lot of time.

Note: The loop over bits may not be how current kernels do it, but that is how it was done way back when.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `select` lets you wait for an i/o event instead of waisting CPU cycles on `read`.

So, in your example, the main loop can look like:

```
for (;;)
{
  int res;
  char buf[256];

  res = read(fileDescriptor1, buf, sizeof(buf));
  if (res > 0)
  {
      printf("Read %d bytes from channel1\n", res);
  }
  res = read(fileDescriptor2, buf, sizeof(buf));
  if (res > 0)
  {
      printf("Read %d bytes from channel2\n", res);
  }
}
```

If you add the code and run it, you would notice that:

- The program actually does what you want - it reads from both pipes.
- CPU utilization is 100% for one core, i.e. program wastes CPU even when there is no data to read.

To solve issue, `select` and `poll` APIs are introduced. For `select` we need to know descriptors (we do), and the maximum out of them.

So let's modify the code a bit:

```
 for (;;)
 {
    fd_set fds;
    int maxfd;

    FD_ZERO(&fds); // Clear FD set for select
    FD_SET(fileDescriptor1, &fds);
    FD_SET(fileDescriptor2, &fds);

    maxfd = fileDescriptor1 > fileDescriptor2 ? fileDescriptor1 : fileDescriptor2;

    select(maxfd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    // The minimum information for select: we are asking only about
    // read operations, ignoring write and error ones; and not
    // defining any time restrictions on wait.


   // do reads as in previous example here
 }
```

When running the improved code, the CPU would not be wasted as much, but you will notice, that the `read` operation is performed even when there is no data for a particular pipe, but there is for another.

To check, which pipe actually has the data, use `FD_ISSET` after `select` call:

```
if (FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor1, &fds))
{
   // We can read from fileDescriptor1
}
if (FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor2, &fds))
{
   // We can read from fileDescriptor2
}
```

So, after joining said above, the code would look like:

```
for (;;)
{
  fd_set fds;
  int maxfd;
  int res;
  char buf[256];

  FD_ZERO(&fds); // Clear FD set for select
  FD_SET(fileDescriptor1, &fds);
  FD_SET(fileDescriptor2, &fds);

  maxfd = fileDescriptor1 > fileDescriptor2 ? fileDescriptor1 : fileDescriptor2;

  select(maxfd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);


  if (FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor1, &fds))
  {
     // We can read from fileDescriptor1
     res = read(fileDescriptor1, buf, sizeof(buf));
     if (res > 0)
     {
        printf("Read %d bytes from channel1\n", res);
     }
  }
  if (FD_ISSET(fileDescriptor2, &fds))
  {
     // We can read from fileDescriptor2
    res = read(fileDescriptor2, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (res > 0)
    {
        printf("Read %d bytes from channel2\n", res);
    }
  }
}
```

So, add error handling, and you would be set.

Comment: You do not waste CPU cycles on read - it blocks (usually). Select enables one to find out what one has data

Comment: @EdHeal the pipes are opened in non-blocking mode. why would they block?

Comment: this kind of line: 'printf("Read %d bytes from channel1\n");'  should probably be more like: 'printf("Read %d bytes from channel1\n", res);'

Comment: note that select() exits as soon as any byte is available from any of the watched FDs.  therefore, any specific read() may (or may not) get all the bytes the writer to the pipe sent.  so in an actual implementation, some form of record identification should be implemented.  Then the usual method is to read only one byte on each itteration, accumulating the bytes into a buffer, and check for a full record being received before actually processing that data.  This is mostly because pipes have no concept of any kind of data structure, so the using program needs to provide that concept.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Are you really sure you can do such thing on named pipe??